# realtime firebase database get property name and value on child_changed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on real-time fire-base database.
i have a issue in getting value what is changed in fire-base.
i have client social database inside it posts and then kkkm(this is key) and then different properties and values and what i want is to toggle approval and rejected values like that approval:true but what i get is just true/false not the property name.

```js
toggleCheck = (id) => {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts/'+id);
    ref.off("child_changed");
    var approval;
    ref.on("child_changed", function (data) {
      approval = data.val();
      console.log("=============================");
      console.log("The updated approval is " + approval);
    });
  }

toggleClose = (id) => {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts/'+id);
    ref.off("child_changed");    
    var rejected;
    ref.on("child_changed", function (data) {
      rejected = data.val();
      console.log(ref.getKey());
      console.log(ref.getValue());
      console.log("=============================");
      console.log("The updated rejected is " + rejected);
    });
}
```

[image: the output i get]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure to understand what you want to do ("toggle approval and rejected values"?) but, based on the code in your question, the following is probably what you are looking for:

```
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + id);
  ref.on('child_changed', function(data) {
    console.log(data.key);  // <-- Name of the field/node that was modified
    console.log(data.val()); // <-- Value of the field/node that was modified
    console.log("The updated" + data.key + " is " + data.val());
  });
```

**Explanations:**

`data` is a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) which has:

1. A [`key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#key) property, which is "the key (last part of the path) of the location of this DataSnapshot."
2. A [`val()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#val) method, which "extracts a JavaScript value from a DataSnapshot."

---

**UPDATE FOLLOWING YOUR COMMENTS**

I understand that you want to get both the values of the `approval` and `rejected` nodes (fields) when something changes in the `post`.

Therefore you should use the `value` event type instead of the `child_changed` one, as follows:

```
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + id);
  ref.on('value', function(data) {
    var approved = data.val().approved;
    var rejected = data.val().rejected;

    var object = {'approved': approved, 'rejected': rejected};
    //Do whatever you want with the object
    console.log(object);

  });
```

Comment: i have list of cards in view and these cards have check and close btn if user click on some card it approves it and when user click on close it rejected it and if the card is approves user change its decision and click on close then 2 properties change in card approval:true to approval:false and rejected:false to rejected:true

Comment: https://client-social.web.app/#/home I am making an app like this check this link

Comment: i want data like this object:{ approval:true/false , rejected : true/false }
right now my code only shows me true/false not the property name(approval/rejected).

Comment: value event calls itself again and again what i do to prevent that

Comment: It's difficult to answer precisely, it depends on your exact requirements. You could either use `ref.on('child_changed', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {})`as you initially do, but it means you have to query the parent node to get the value of `approved` or `rejected`, since you are listening at the level of the `approved` or `rejected` nodes. Or maybe you should use the once() method which "listens for exactly one event of the specified event type, and then stops listening.", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#once

Comment: Thanks you help me alot